# How can I tell my server to allow logins via a mail client?

Tags: postfix, smtp, sendmail, dovecot, imap

I am setting up my first sendmail daemon on centos, using virtual domains and emails. So far, I have got it working and emails sent from remote servers will make it to the inbox.

The problem I have is actually logging in to the server with a mail client.

I have setup an mx record (about 36 hours ago), e.g. mail.mydomain.org, and also one for mydomain.org. I don't know if I need both.

**The problem is:** When I try to add an IMAP account on a mail client, it tells me it the server is not responding. The same when I get to adding the SMTP.

So I'm guessing these ports aren't open, and I haven't configured the server to listen on IMAP or SMTP properly.

I have installed Dovecot, which I understand handles imap requests for Postfix, but i'm such a newb that I'm struggling to work out if my server is using sendmail or postfix.

Any tips in the right direction, or what I can check for?

Comment: Check if your server accepts SMTP and IMAP connections only on loopback (127.0.0.1) interface. `nestat -ant` | grep :25` . `nestat -ant` | grep :143`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MX record does not indicate much of anything to the client.  Mail clients look up the A or AAAA record for the DNS name provided as the IMAP or SMTP (or POP3) server.  MX records are for providing an indication of which servers are mail exchangers for your domain (eg. which server to send mails to when the recipient is at your domain).

It's either the case that the ports are blocked by a firewall, DNS resolution isn't working or is giving out the wrong address, or the service you're looking to access isn't running.

Check that, if your mail client is trying to use SSL to connect, your IMAP and SMTP daemons are actually configured to accept SSL connections.  If you don't want to do that, turn SSL off in the client settings.

Check that the DNS names you're specifying in the client for the SMTP and IMAP servers are correct, and that you can open a connection (using telnet or something) to that host on the appropriate ports (eg. 25 and 143).  If you want, try doing an IMAP or SMTP session yourself in the telnet client and see if it gives out the right responses.

Consider checking your logs on the server for any obvious errors.

Comment: thank you for that. looking at /var/log/maillog there is no activity at all when my client attempts to connect.

Comment: My client gives the option of using SSL or not, either way, neither makes a connection.

Comment: I can ssh into mydomain.org, but not mail.mydomain.org

Comment: SSH is not an especially useful diagnostic tool for this.  Anyway, check what the latter host resolves to; there is likely your problem.

Comment: You were right. It was dns poorly setup. I had the domain setup as an MX record, as well as mail.domain.etc. Cheers